# Ubuntu not showing hard drive

Tags: windows-7, linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning

I have a laptop which had a broken installation of Windows 7 installed on it.

I created a Ubuntu live USB and tried installing Ubuntu over that Windows 7. After a few minutes, I got an error message, so I needed to restart the computer. Now the laptop says that there is no bootable device - reasonable message given that there was an error during Linux installation. However:

1. BIOS can see my hard drive,
2. When I start Ubuntu in live mode, and try either `sudo fdisk -l` or gparted, it doesn't show any hard disk drives.

I am 90% sure that the hard drive is broken, but it is weird that BIOS can see it, and Ubuntu doesn't. How can I be 100% sure about that hard drive? Is there any additional way of detecting my hard drive from Ubuntu?

Comment: Try typing `dmesg | less` and peruse the output for any references to disk devices (including the string `sda`, assuming you've got just the one disk). This might show you an error message or some other clue about what's going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Go into your bios and try disabling/enabling AHCI. Reboot, and see if anything changes for you. Don't forget to re-enable/disable it if it doesn't solve your problem though. :)